# Metabase - How to use custom JDBC driver? (Databricks)

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, databricks, metabase

I'm trying to connect Metabase in my data source that is in Databricks.
I tried to use the SparkSQL connector that comes with Metabase but didn't work. Metabase generates a slightly different jdbc connection url that it should be, Metabase generates a url that begins with `jdbc:hive2` but Databricks requires a url that starts with `jdbc:spark`.

Databricks provide a Simba Spark JDBC Driver to use for connection. I already used this driver to connect to Databricks with other BI tools and IDEs like Datagrip for example and works perfectly, so I think must be a way to configure Metabase to use this "custom" driver jar to connect to Databricks.

If anyone wants to download the simba driver they provide: http://info.databricks.com/do0hZ6qCUq0Sj00Mjk000Y0

Someone already did something related to that and can help me? Thanks!